# How to connect to the a Linux machine behind a router via ssh tunnel

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, router, tunnel

I'm using Windows system (Machine W). I want to a Linux machine (Machine L) behind a router via ssh tunnel. I have another Linux machine (Machine T) to establish ssh tunnel. I want only packets for machine L to be forward via Machine T since some hosts such as local-network hosts only can be reached by Machine W. So I hope to archive such architecture:

```
W----------------T-----router-----L
|<--ssh tunnel-->|
|
|--the other connections
```

Comment: What are you going to do at the application level?

Comment: I want to connect to the Machine L to wtite, compile and run programs.

Comment: I am not seeing a connection between `T machine` and `L machine behind router`. Can you `ping` L machine? Can you ping router? Will you able to login to router to set up SSH port forwarding?

Comment: how does machine T initiate a connection to machine L?  ANd am I correct in assuming that "router" means "firewall I can't go directly through"?